# Using AWS lambda with python or java code to get JSON from RestAPI call and insert into oracle DB

Tags: java, python, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can i use AWS lambda to call a RestAPI and iterate thru JSON, extract and load data into oracle DB on AWS RDS by passing the parameters to an oracle package? If yes can someone please let me know to secure credentials to call RestAPI and Oracle user?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager), Here is a [good guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-securely-provide-database-credentials-to-lambda-functions-by-using-aws-secrets-manager/) from AWS.

Comment: Can we call Oracle PL SQL package from Python on Lambda? Does aws provide sdk for that?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer pointed out, you can use  AWS Secrets Manager if you want to store secrets. But its most useful when you are working with AWS Managed RDS Oracle DB. Its not clear from your question whether this is the case.

If that is not the case, then [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) with `SecretString` type could be better, as it is **free** (AWS Secrets Manager is not free).

AWS does not provide build-in SDKs in lambda for different databases. However, Orcale provides [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/) which is module for Python. To use that on lambda you would have to construct a **custom  development package** or your own [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to use `cx_Oracle`.

To sum up, I don't see a reason why you wouldn't be able to use lambda to work with your DB. However, this is something that will not work out-of-the box and requires some development.

Comment: @Shashi No problem. In this case,  Secret Manger [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html#full-rotation-support)  RDS Oracle and rotation of its secrets.

Comment: Thanks @marcin can I do the same to call rest api because they might ask me to pass user secret key etc to authenticate.

Comment: @Shashi Yes, you can get the credentials form the secret manager. You lambda would need to have execution role permissions to access it. And aws provides SDK for access it, e.g. [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html).